# Python - Matplotlib not showing any axis labels on twin plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am unable to see any labels on this plot and I have specified labels for each axis. The same thing is happening with the x axis showing as 0,2,4, rather than 0,1,2,3,4 etc.
For reference - I am using this within my PySimpleGUI code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data2= [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,133,121,123]
data3=[100,324,121,432,232,543,332,543,534,122]
data4=[100,312,111,111,322,443,545,122,345,122]
#plt.style.use('dark_background')
title="my graph"
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] ='white'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '8'
plt.bar(data1,data2, color= 'blue' ,width=0.5,label="data2")
plt.twinx()
plt.plot(data1, data3, label="data 3 label")
plt.plot(data1, data4,label="data4",color='green')
plt.xlabel("my x axis label",fontsize =8)
plt.title(title,fontsize=8)
plt.tight_layout()
fig = plt.gcf()
print(fig)
```

[image: plot example here]
Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clean-up using the object-oriented interface:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] ='white'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '8'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

ax.bar(data1,data2, color= 'blue' ,width=0.5,label="data2")

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data1, data3, label="data 3 label")
ax2.plot(data1, data4,label="data4",color='green')

ax.set_xlabel("my x axis label",fontsize =8)
ax.set_xticks(data1)
ax.set_title(title,fontsize=8)

fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]

Perhaps better to use `MultipleLocator` for the tick positions (credit for the idea to @JohanC):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
...
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
```

Comment: thank you!!! I spent HOURS searching so I really appreciate it. Would it be possible to put labels for for the y axis as well?

Comment: `ax.set_ylabel(...)`?

Answer (score -1):

Try using plt.axes() to separate it, as shown

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data2= [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,133,121,123]
data3=[100,324,121,432,232,543,332,543,534,122]
data4=[100,312,111,111,322,443,545,122,345,122]
#plt.style.use('dark_background')
title="my graph"
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] ='white'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '8'
ax = plt.axes()
ax.bar(data1,data2, color= 'blue' ,width=0.5,label="data2")
ax2 = plt.twinx()
ax2.plot(data1, data3, label="data 3 label")
ax2.plot(data1, data4,label="data4",color='green')
ax2.set_xlabel("my x axis label",fontsize =8)
plt.title(title,fontsize=8)
plt.tight_layout()
fig = plt.gcf()
print(fig)
```

Comment: This seems to be identical to the code in the question, you are simply explicitly using the Axes objects while `plt` does it implicitly. From the [Pyplot tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html): 'In matplotlib.pyplot various states are preserved across function calls, so that it keeps track of things like the current figure and plotting area, and the plotting functions are directed to the current axes'